# What is corect way to configure path to packages for perl?

Tags: perl

I may configure location of packages for perl via `PERL5LIB`, `-Ipath/to/libs` option, `use lib LIST`. But what if I add paths into `@INC` manually: `BEGIN{ unshift @INC, './local' }`

Why perl do not add add `site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux` and `5.30.3/x86_64-linux` automatically?

Comment: Could you add a minimal example that illustrates the problem? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: To my knowledge local::lib does that sort of things.

Comment: local::lib sets PERL5LIB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tell Perl to add one string to an array, so Perl adds one string to the array. If you want to add other strings too, you will need to add those other strings too.

Or use one of the three methods you listed that does what you want.

Besides, `./local` isn't the right path. It means `local` in the current work directory. It doesn't mean `local` in the same directory the script is located. For that, you want

```perl
use RealBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/local";
```

Comment: So direct manipulation of `@INC` is not so correct way to tell perl about libraries (yeah, technically it works fine, but to not forget some folders I should use tools, like `-I` and `use lib`, should not?

Comment: It's not incorrect, but it's definitely not the easiest way.